# What do i do wrong (c language with file.txt)

Tags: c

There is a following exercise:

I have a `file.txt` containing a lot of unknown numbers, separated by one or more spaces or by a new line.(`file.txt` in one folder with my program).

I must find total amount of numbers and maximum value. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *in;
    in=fopen("file.txt","r");
    int arr[100],i=0,j,max;
    while(fscanf(in,"%d",&arr[i] != EOF)) {
        i++;
    }
    arr[0]=max;
    for(j=1;j<i;j++) {
        if(max < arr[j]) {
            max = arr[j];
        }
    }
    printf("Tot.number: %d\nMax: %d",i,max);
}
```

But, codeblock cannot execute the program.

Comment: _"codeblock cannt execute the programm"_ is not a problem description... Why not? What error did it give you? [Edit] your post to quote it in full.

Comment: `arr[0] = max;` Where is `max` initialized?

Comment: You would save yourself considerable trouble if you avoided recording the numbers in an array.  You don't need to do that for your purposes -- you can instead track the minimum and maximum as you go, as you do their count, without preserving the individual numbers across subsequent reads.

Answer (score 3):

```
fscanf(in,"%d",&arr[i] != EOF)
```

will be

```
fscanf(in,"%d",&arr[i]) != EOF
```

But there are other problems also

- Not checking the return value of `fopen`.

  ```
  if(in != NULL ){
     /* File opened correctly */
  }
  ```
- No guard while accessing the array. if `i>=100` there will be array index out of bound error leading to undefined behavior.
- You forgot to <strike>declare</strike> initialize `max`.
- You meant to initialize `max` to `arr[0]`. So correct will be `max = arr[0]`. There is no use assigning value of `arr[0]` in case you want to find the maximum.
- Also you have to keep in mind that if `fscanf` doesn't return `EOF` then you can't be relieved that it worked unless you check that 2 value is being parsed correctly. The output of `fscanf` should be equal to 1 since one value is being read.

  ```
  int r = fscanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  if( r == 1 ){
     /* SUCCESS */
  }
  else if( errno ) {
     /* Error occured */
  }
  else if( r == EOF ){
     /* Either EOF reached or some I/O error. */
  }
  ```

Also among other things (not an error but a good practice)

- Not closing the file.

  ```
  fclose(in);
  ```

Comment: I was just about to mention the #3 in your problems part. Good note.. :-)

Comment: Not closing the file is perhaps a style problem, but one can rely on any open files being closed automatically if the program terminates normally.

Comment: @JohnBollinger.: It is a good practice.

Comment: @coderredoc : There are other issues too with `fscanf` because the input file the user supplies can't be trusted entirely to contain numbers. Worth mentioning that too..

Comment: @sjsam.: Hm..yes. Edited.